# Skipping entry in edit text

Tags: android

I have some EditText in my application and when I click on any of them and start typing, after typing first letter focus is cleared and I get this warnning on LogCat :

> Skipping entry 0x106007b in package table 0 because it is not complex!

does anyone know what does it mean  ? I searched this on google and got zero result !!!

Comment: I think this link helps you - http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/12/skipping-entry-in-package-table-0.html

Comment: It didn't. I couldn't find 0x106007b in my R.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest file for you activity
and for edittext add below parameters-

```
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```